TypeORM: Select a field from one model based on another model, with additional authentication
I work on a NestJS / Typeorm application with 3 entity : Category, Resource and User.
Category has simply a name field. Resource got an alreadyRead (boolean) field. User is for Auth.
I try to make a query to get from the Category entity all existing categories for my user, and also an array of resources that have alreadyRead set to false.
Here is my query :
    const categories = await this.categoryRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('category')
      .leftJoin('category.resources', 'resource')
      .select(['category', 'resource.alreadyRead'])
      .where('resource.user.id = :userId', { userId: user.id })
      .andWhere(
        new Brackets((qb) => {
          qb.where('resource.alreadyRead = :alreadyRead', {
            alreadyRead: false,
          }).orWhere('resource.id IS NULL');
        }),
      )
      .getMany();

My issue : if my user has an empty category, my request doesn't return it. Thx for your help !
